# React Native pan gesture handler not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I was following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/r5XXSb4yQes (code: https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/tree/master/season3/src/CoinbasePro) and did what he said but I cannot make the scrubber (horizontal & vertical line) work.

As you can see, even if I press/drag, the scrubber/line doesn't appear.

[image]

**Expected** horizontal and vertical line when PanGestureHandler is triggered:

[image]

Below is the relevant code:

MainScreen:

```js
import Animated, {
  add,
  diffClamp,
  eq,
  modulo,
  sub,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { useValues, onGestureEvent } from "react-native-redash/lib/module/v1";
import { PanGestureHandler, State } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Svg, { Line } from "react-native-svg";
import data from "../../utils/data";

const MainScreen = () => {
  
  const caliber = data.length > 0 ? width / data.length : 0;

  const [x, y, state] = useValues(0, 0, State.UNDETERMINED);
  const gestureHandler = onGestureEvent({ x, y, state });
  const opacity = eq(state, State.ACTIVE);
  const translateY = diffClamp(y, 0, width);
  const translateX = add(sub(x, modulo(x, caliber)), caliber / 2);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* CHART INFO START */}
      <Animated.View style={{ opacity }} pointerEvents="none">
        <ChartInfo candles={data} translateX={translateX} caliber={caliber} />
      </Animated.View>
      {/* CHART INFO END */}

      <View>
        {/* CHART START */}
        <Chart
          candles={data}
          size={width}
          caliber={caliber}
          domain={calculateMinMaxCandles(data)}
        />
        {/* CHART END */}
        <PanGestureHandler minDist={0} {...gestureHandler}>
          <Animated.View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
            {/* HORIZONTAL LINE START */}
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
                opacity,
                transform: [{ translateY }],
              }}
            >
              <ScrubberLine x={width} y={0} />
            </Animated.View>
            {/* HORIZONTAL LINE END */}

            {/* VERTICAL LINE START */}
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
                opacity,
                transform: [{ translateX }],
              }}
            >
              <ScrubberLine x={0} y={width} />
            </Animated.View>
            {/* VERTICAL LINE END */}
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const ScrubberLine = ({ x, y }) => {
  return (
    <Svg style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
      <Line
        x1={0}
        y1={0}
        x2={x}
        y2={y}
        strokeWidth={2}
        stroke="#B5B6B7"
        strokeDasharray="6 6"
      />
    </Svg>
  );
};
```

ChartInfo.js

```js
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import {
  call,
  divide,
  floor,
  onChange,
  useCode,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import * as Haptics from "expo-haptics";
import styles from "./style";

const ChartInfo = ({ translateX, caliber, candles }) => {
  const [{ timestamp, open, close, high, low }, setCandle] = useState(
    candles[0]
  );
  useCode(
    () =>
      onChange(
        translateX,
        call([floor(divide(translateX, caliber))], ([index]) => {
          Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light);
          setCandle(candles[index]);
        })
      ),
    [caliber, candles, translateX]
  );
  const diff = `${((close - open) * 100) / open}`;
  const change = close - open < 0 ? diff.substring(0, 5) : diff.substring(0, 4);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.table}>
        <View style={styles.column}>
          <Row label="Open" value={open} />
          <Row label="Close" value={close} />
          <Row label="Volume" value="" />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.separator} />
        <View style={styles.column}>
          <Row label="High" value={high} />
          <Row label="Low" value={low} />
          <Row
            label="Change"
            value={`${change}%`}
            color={close - open > 0 ? "#4AFA9A" : "#E33F64"}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default ChartInfo;

const Row = ({ label, value }) => (
  <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.label}>{label}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.value}>{value}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-haptics": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
```

I have been debugging it for days and cannot find what I'm doing wrong, it is exactly the same as mentioned in his tutorial. Can someone please help me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap it all in a GestureHandlerRootView , like this

```
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
...
return(
<GestureHandlerRootView>
{...} Your views
</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

That should work.